# How to recover data and partition after diskpart clean

Tags: data-recovery, diskpart

While installing Windows 10 from the Repair Tools command prompt, I ran `clean` command by mistake on the whole disk, so it becomes a single 465GB partition. Previously, it contained four partitions.

How can I recover them with the data intact?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you haven't made any more writes to the disk, I believe [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) should easily be able to fix this for you.

Just in case something goes wrong or if this otherwise does not work, I would advise you first take a raw image of the disk's current state, so you can roll back your changes and not put your data at any more unnecessary risk.

Comment: Thanks alot... I have recovered using testdisk and all my partitions are there, but now there is no operating system. I had formatted c drive before I lost partitions so c drive is empty and small 100mb windows volume is shown as unallocated space. When I start my computer is gives the message that No operating system found. What should I do now?

Comment: @K.Ketan It probably restored the last known state of your bootsector from the point after where you had formatted your filesystem. Use something that will ignore the filesystem and scrape for raw data, like [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec).

Comment: I've installed fresh copy of windows, But one of the partition which was previously of 80 gb is recovered like 50gb of one and 30gb un allocated space. I lost the data from it. 50gb partiiton is not formatted.What to do with testdisk. And at the time of booting chkdisk run and 'MFT currupted' message shown. But 'windows failed to recover MFT' is displayed then computer boots.

Comment: @K.Ketan You can try restoring your Master File Table from a backup copy kept by NTFS. In TestDisk, select that partition, and under Boot, select `Repair MFT`. From the sound of it, though, even your backup copy could be hosed at this point.

Answer (score -2):

I did it by mistake too.
Just use "list volume" in order to see if it is still present, you should see the partition's size but no letter assigned to it.
Use "assign" and it will work.