# Can I recover data after diskpart 'clean' and 'convert gpt' commands

Tags: data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, diskpart

I accidentally deleted all my data while windows installation setup by running diskpart 'clean' command. :( Then I executed 'convert gpt' command and all my data was gone. I did not copy anything to my HDD after and is there any chance to recover my data again?

By googling I found by following [these steps](https://superuser.com/questions/1001110/how-to-recover-data-and-partition-after-diskpart-clean) using TestDisk has some silver line to recover my data. But since I executed 'convert gpt' will it be possible?

Comment: Duplicate the steps in the link, starting with making a disk image.

Comment: But what I wanna know is whther 'convert gpt' command can wipe my data out or not?

Comment: You'll have to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recovered my lost partitions using *Mini tool power data recovery*. I could recover all my partitions since I haven't had overwritten by data.

Also tools like *Recuva* can be used. Additionally I tried using free versions of these tools but it didn't work and licensed version needed. So in a such a situation TestDisk open source (free) tool can be used. The one I mentioned above.

*`clean` command entered before MBR to GPT conversion deletes only partition table. So the data can be recovered.*